# php isset is not working with submit button

Tags: php, html, post, form-submit, isset

I'm trying to create a login page using php, and I want my code to check the username and password given after the log in button is pressed. But the code executes even if the log in button is not pressed. I've searched dozens of code online and almost all of them were implemented this way so I can't understand what is wrong here. Here is my code :

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Welcome to FoodOrder - Log In or Sign Up</TITLE>

    </HEAD>
    <BODY background = "foodOrder.png">

        <?php
        session_start();
        $con = mysqli_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect, please check your username and password: ".mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!= ""){
            header("Location: home.php");
        } 

        if(isset($_POST["login_button"])){
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
            $sql = "SELECT password from user where username  = '$username'";
            $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
            if($row['password'] == md5($password)){
                $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                header("Location : home.php");
            } else {
                ?> <script>alert('wrong username or password');</script> <?php
            }
        }


        ?>

        <center>
            <div id ="login form">
                <form  method = "POST">
                    <table align = "center" width = "25%" border = "0">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type = "text" name = "username" placeholder = "your_username_here" required></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type = "text" name = "password" placeholder = "your_password_here"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type = "submit" name = "login_button"  value = "Log In" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href = "register.php">Sign Up</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </center>

    </BODY>



</HTML>
```

Comment: I hope those aren't you real credentials.. Which code executes if the `log in` isn't pressed? You also shouldn't escape input that isn't going to the db, a password with a quote will be hashed incorrectly this way. You also shouldn't use `md5` for passwords.

Comment: despite edit, if those were your credentials reset your account. Credentials could already be compromised and are still present in revisions.

Comment: @chris85 It's going to the db correctly, but it's saved in the session wrongly.

Comment: Correct @chris85 `:D`

Comment: In My system. This Code Working Fine.

Comment: Have you checked if the if statement is true. Put this in your php script var_dump($_POST); What is the output?

Comment: Can you explain which part of the code is running? For example, is it the `header("Location : home.php");` that is running or the javascript `alert`?

Comment: Don't escape your password. There is absolutely no reason for it as you're not passing its value to the query. In escaping it you run the risk of actually altering the user's password, ie. my inputted password of `marcus's` now becomes, per your escape method, `marcus\'s` which is then hashed and will not match. Leave the password alone.

Comment: the code after the if(isset($_POST["login_button"])) is executed which in my understanding shouldn't run if the button "login_button" is not pressed.

Comment: db is not the problem here the code works when i submit a valid username and password but my if statement which chekcs the submit button seems useless as it executes the below code anyhow

Comment: @NanaPatrykar does the browser gives you wrong uname password message when you first open it ?

Comment: You get `wrong username or password` in an alert? Is that the issue we are debugging? Guess would be the page is a `.html` and all the PHP is in the HTML source as text.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code by removing the `md5` once. The `$_SESSION` VARIABLE is not working correctly.

Also try replacing this

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!= ""){
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
```

with this

```
if(!$_SESSION['user']){
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
```

Comment: Why do you have the exclamation mark inside your isset? `isset(!$_SESSION['user'])`

Comment: It will check that the $_SESSION variable has anything or not.

Comment: Pretty sure that's an error. **E_COMPILE_ERROR : type 64 -- Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it hasn't worked for me. Maybe it dealth with future errors but the runtime still thinks that the button is pressed(even if its not) and continues after the if(isset....) statement.